# How to find certain value in list Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift

This is my code

```
let daysOfTheWeek = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]
let day = Int.random(in: 1 ... 7)
```

I want it to get the random number from 1 to 7 then I want it to print what is in that index in my days of the week code but I don't Know how can you please help?

Comment: What is the output of `print(daysOfTheWeek[day])` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, since arrays in Swift start from index 0, you should probably change the range of your random index to `0...6` (or even better to `daysOfTheWeek.startIndex..<daysOfTheWeek.endIndex`) and print the string that `daysOfTheWeek` has in `day` index, like this:

```
let daysOfTheWeek = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]
let day = Int.random(in: daysOfTheWeek.startIndex..<daysOfTheWeek.endIndex)
print(daysOfTheWeek[day])
```

**Update**: In the words of @LeoDabus in the comments:

> There is no need to reinvent the wheel

since `weekdaySymbols` property of `Calendar` provides a list of all the weekdays and using `randomElement()` function you can get a random one:

```
let randomDay = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols.randomElement()
print(randomDay ?? "nil")
```

Comment: Besides the fact that collection indices are zero based in Swift there is no need to reinvent the wheel. `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols.randomElement()`

Comment: @LeoDabus oh certainly! I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sort and sweet.

```
let daysOfTheWeek = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]

if let day = daysOfTheWeek.randomElement(),
   let index = daysOfTheWeek.firstIndex(of: day) {
    // Do your stuf here
    print("Day : ", day)
    print("Day Index : ", index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let daysOfTheWeek = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]

let day = Int.random(in: 0 ... 6)

print(daysOfTheWeek[day])
```